# get Coursera video download link via program

Tags: javascript, java, python, python-requests, coursera-api

I want extract Coursera video download link via program(mainly Python)  behind those links

https://www.coursera.org/learn/human-computer-interaction/lecture/s4rFQ/the-interaction-design-specialization

https://www.coursera.org/learn/calculus1/lecture/IYGhT/why-is-calculus-going-to-be-so-much-fun

After red a lot of articles about this, still  cannot find a way to extract the video download link via program, anyone can offer a step by step solution of extracting the video download link ? Thanks!

P.S. I know [this](https://github.com/coursera-dl/coursera) project , but the code is so complex , so I dropped out.

---

Thanks for answering, I have succeeded made a chrome extension to download the video http://mathjoy.tumblr.com/post/130547895523/mediadownloader

Comment: downloading your extension from Google Drive requires a person to have a Google Account, and, furthermore, to request access from you. Could you please change permissions to "anyone with a link can view"? Also, One Drive link is dead.

Comment: @izogfif Thanks for your tip. I shared it to the public again.

Answer (score 1):

I made myself a Coursera-Downloader today using [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) , [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html) package , [chromewebdriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads).(these 3 tools are needed in the rest of the answer)

first of all you need to find the course you want in coursera and enroll in it.
after that you should complete the code below and run it. it will take a while but the result(all video links) will be written inside a text file:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# ########################### #
# ####-fill these vars-###### #
# ########################### #

# coursera login information:

username = "~"  # e.g. : username = "john@doe.com"
password = "~"  # e.g. : password = "12345asdfg"

# course details to download IMPORTANT: you should be enrolled in the course

path_course = "https://www.coursera.org/learn/programming-languages/home/week/1"  # link to the course first week e.g. : path_course = "https://www.coursera.org/learn/game-theory-1/home/week/1"
num_of_weeks = 5  # number of course weeks(or desired weeks to download) e.g. : num_of_weeks = 5
path_to_save = "E:\\programming-languages-coursera-links.txt"  # path to the file in wich the links will be saved e.g. : path_to_save = "E:\\interactive-python-links.txt"
#############################
#############################
#############################
print_each_link = False


# defining functions :
def get_links_of_week(week_add):
    """
    this function gets the download links from the course.
    :param week_add: address to the specific week in order to get links
    :return: a list containing all download links regarding the specific week.
    """
    driver.get(week_add)
    print("going for" + week_add)
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
    links = []
    for elem in elems:
        sublink = elem.get_attribute("href")
        # print(sublink)
        if sublink.find("lecture") != -1 and sublink not in links:
            links.append(sublink)
    # print("---------------")
    # print(links)
    inner_links = []

    for link in links:
        driver.get(link)
        driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        inner_elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
        for inelem in inner_elems:
            sub_elem = inelem.get_attribute("href")

            # print(sub_elem)
            if sub_elem.find("mp4") != -1:
                print("the link : " + sub_elem[37:77] + "... fetched")
                inner_links.append(sub_elem)

    return inner_links


def get_week_list():
    """
    this function gets the URL address from predefined variables from the top
    :return: a list containing each week main page.
    """
    weeks = []
    print('list of weeks are : ')
    for x in range(1, num_of_weeks + 1):
        weeks.append(path_course[:-1] + str(x))
        print(path_course[:-1] + str(x))
    return weeks


# loading chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome("E:\\chromedriver.exe")
# login to Coursera
driver.get(path_course)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
email = driver.find_element_by_name("email")
email.click()
email.send_keys(username)
pas = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
pas.click()
pas.send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"rendered-content\"]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/form/button").send_keys(
    Keys.RETURN)

# fetching links from each week web page
weeks_link = get_week_list()
all_links = []
for week in weeks_link:
    all_links += get_links_of_week(week)
driver.close()

# write to file
print("now writing to file ...")
text_file = open(path_to_save, "w")
for each_link in all_links:
    if print_each_link:
        print(each_link + "\n")
    text_file.write(each_link)
    text_file.write("\n")
text_file.close()
print("---------------------------------")
print("all Links are fetched successfully")
```

comment here if you got into any trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [RequestsLib](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) to make requests to the pages, login, etc, and [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to parse the resulting data.  The general idea is something like

```
r = requests.get(url_you_want)
domTree = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
link=domTree.find(id="WhateverIDTheLinkHasInTheDownloadPage")
[...etc...]
```

I can't help you if you want someone to do the entirety of the work for you, though...

Comment: yes, I know the two packages, I am also able to login in Coursera via Python, the difficulty is how to find out  the video download link from the page.

Comment: Does the link have a specific class or ID in the source?  Hopefully one of these two things will be true;  the alternative is to try and see if it appears in the same place in the DOM tree each time.